# Probability of + character occurrence in base64 encoded string

Tags: math, base64, combinations, probability

I have over 6 million DB records containing base64 encoded string values.
These are SHA-256 output of random 13 digit numbers.
When I counted with SQL LIKE query, it is over 3 million.

I want to know whether is it normal.
So I tried to calculate the probability of + character occurrence.

Could you confirm this calculation?

```
(64^44 - 63^44) / 64^44
```

(Base64 encoding consist of 64 characters)

[Wolfram Alpha says, its 0.5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(64%5E44%20-%2063%5E44)%20%2F%2064%5E44)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Number of base-64 digits needed to represent an SHA-256 checksum = `256 / log2(64) = 42.6666... = 43`
- Probability of one character not being `+` = `63/64`
- Probability of *all* characters not being `+` = `(63/64)^43`
- Therefore probability of *at least* one being `+` = `1 - (63/64)^43 = (64^43 - 63^43) / (64^43)`

So your answer was almost correct - just assumed the wrong number of digits. The numerical value is still correct within reasonable error.